# Gstreamer: display and record H264 stream simultaneously

Tags: gstreamer, h.264

Using gst-launch-1.0 I am able record a H.264 stream to a file with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video3 do-timestamp=true \
! video/x-h264, width=$WIDTH, height=$HEIGHT, framerate=$FRAMERATE/1 \ 
! h264parse ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink location=video.mp4
```

and I am able to display the stream with:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video3 \
! video/x-h264, width=$WIDTH,height=$HEIGHT,framerate=$FRAMERATE/1 ! tee name=t \
t. ! queue ! h264parse ! decodebin ! xvimagesink sync=false
```

However, doing both things on the same time fails. Then nothing happens. Command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video3 \
! video/x-h264,width=$WIDTH,height=$HEIGHT,framerate=$FRAMERATE/1 ! tee name=t \
t. ! queue ! h264parse ! decodebin ! xvimagesink sync=false \
t. ! queue ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4
```

Output: (no error - but no display and filesize = 0kB)

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:t.GstTeePad:src_0: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:t.GstTeePad:src_1: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTee:t.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse2.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse2.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad0: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse2.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstH264Parse:h264parse2.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstOMXH264Dec-omxh264dec:omxh264dec-omxh264dec0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter1.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, width=(int)640, height=(int)480, framerate=(fraction)15/1, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)au, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)2:4:7:1, parsed=(boolean)true, profile=(string)main, level=(string)4.1
```

Comment: what is the output you get when it fails ? (gst-launch-1.0 -vvv should tell you)

Comment: @PrabhakarLad I updated the questions to supply this. Funny thing is that I am not given any error. But no display pops up and the filesize of the recorded file is 0kB.

Comment: can you try if this pipeline works  "gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! queue ! x264enc ! h264parse ! tee name=t ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4 t. ! queue ! h264parse ! decodebin ! xvimagesink sync=false" ? Also can you check if your CPU is taking too much of processing ?

Comment: That works! The displayed video "flickers" quite a bit, but the saved video is good.

Comment: try dropping with sync=false, and see if video still flickers

Comment: Still flickers without sync=false.